# Let $Z=xy$ and $x+2y=1$ and $x,y \ge 0$. Then Max $Z=?$

Tags: calculus

I have a question:

Let $Z=xy$ and $x+2y=1$ and $x,y \ge 0$. Then  Max $Z=?$

Thanks ahead.

Comment: lagrange multiplier??

Comment: Does it work..?

Comment: $x = 1 - 2y \Rightarrow Z = y - 2y^2 \Rightarrow Z' = 1 - 4y = 0 \Rightarrow y = 1/4 \Rightarrow \max{Z} = 1/8$.

Comment: @M.Vinay : why don't you make it as an answer... ? +1 from my side..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x/2+ x/2 +y+y=1$ Use AM$\geq$GM.

GM of these 4 quantities is $(x^2.y^2/4)^{(1/4)}$. This should be less than AM, which is $1/4$.

This gives max Z=1/8, after calculation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

$x +  2y = 1 \Rightarrow x = 1 - 2y \Rightarrow Z = y - 2y^2 \Rightarrow Z' = 1 - 4y = 0 \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{1}{4} \Rightarrow \boxed{\max Z = \dfrac{1}{8}}$

> $\left[Z''_{y = 1/4} = -4 > 0 \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{1}{4}\ \text{is a maximum point}\right]$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik There! :P

Comment: This is much better :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways for solving the problem. The simplest (to me) is to extract $y$ from the constraint so $y=\frac{1-x}{2}$ and so $$Z=\frac{x(1-x)}{2}$$ is the function you want to maximize. Computing $Z'$ is simple and $Z'=0$ if $x=\frac{1}{2}$ which means $y=\frac{1}{4}$ and a maximum for $Z$ equal to $Z_{max}=\frac{1}{8}$. The second derivative test confirms that this ia a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: We have
$$8xy=(x+2y)^2-(x-2y)^2=1-(x-2y)^2.$$
So the maximum value of $8xy$ is $1$, achieved when $x-2y=0$.